# How to change font in title of sidebar widget

Tags: sidebar

I'm not sure if this question belongs in the CSS forum or the WordPress forum...

At this link to my wordpress site: http://richardclunan.com/ in the sidebar, there's a title for a widget "GET FREE CHAPTERS PLUS MORE HELPFUL COPYWRITING IDEAS" - I'd like to change the font of widget titles, so it's not all-caps. So it's small and bold.

How do I do that?

I'm a novice. Where would do i go to find the right file; what's the file name; what code do i need to find to change; and what code do i use as the change?

Comment: You can use firefox's firebug, find the line of css that styles the titles, and then change it.

Comment: I'm a novice. Where would do i go to find the right file; what's the file name; what code do i need to find to change; and what code do i use as the change? I'll update the question with this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It definitely belongs to CSS forum, but any way:

Open: your style.css located in wp-content/themes/twentyeleven-child/

Go to: line 1736 where it says .widget-title

Remove: `text-transform: uppercase;`